# How to delete multiple pictures only when mouse is pressed?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mouse-listeners

I have a problem with mouselisteners. I am trying to create a game where you have to connect pictures while dragging your mouse (clicked).  I am now trying to delete multiple icons while I press my left mouse button down and drag it over the other pictures. Now the pictures are removed when I move my mouse over them but this should only happen when I hold the mouse button down.

```
public void addListeners() {
    /*@Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        super.mouseReleased(null);
    */

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() ==  MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            clicked= true;
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (clicked== true)
            setIcon(null);
           }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            clicked = false;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: A small suggestion: you might want to code in english. It makes it easier to understand for most of the programmers on earth (= on stackoverflow) and it's a bit less knullig :D

Answer (score 0):

In your mouse entered event, your if check is performing an assignment, not an equals operation. The assignment operation is returning the new value, which in this case means your condition is always met, since you're assigning it to true. It should be

```
if (geklikt == true) //(2 equal signs)
```